# How can I delete voicemail number in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, voicemail

I have Nokia lumia 730. It has windows phone 8.1 OS. By mistake one of my contact get's added in **VoiceMail**. When I call to that number it shows me the name **voicemail** in dial history. I want to remove this contact from voicemail. How can I remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit the voicemail number, go to Settings, swipe over to applications and select "phone". Alternatively, open the Phone app, expand the app bar by tapping on "..." and select "settings".

Once there, you can change the voicemail number to something else.

Note that there doesn't currently seem to be any way to delete the voicemail number. If you empty the textbox, the phone will automatically switch to the default voicemail number, which is either set by your carrier or the first one you entered manually. In your case it's probably still your contact's phone number, so currently you'll have to disable the "Use default voicemail number" option and manually set the voicemail number to something else. It can be a fictional/invalid number, or maybe your carrier's actual voicemail number (even if you don't have voicemail service).

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to delete the voicemail number. I don't want to change the voicemail number.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, there seems to be no way to actually remove the voicemail number. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok. If I remove the contact number from voicemail then which number should I enter instead of that?

Comment: Any number you want. I entered my carrier's actual voicemail number (even though I don't use the service), but you can also enter a fictional or invalid number, like "0" (zero), if you want.

Comment: I removed existing number and entered 00000000 as voicemail but still it is taking my old voicemail number

Comment: Do you mean that when you tap the "voicemail" button in the Phone app, it dials the old number? Did you disable the "Use default voicemail number" option?

Comment: Yes I disable `Use default voicemail number` option. removed my old number and added 0000000000 this number. After adding I turn on the `Use default voicemail number` option. Still it is taking my old number

Comment: Do **not** turn on the "Use default voicemail number" option. The default number is stuck to the old number, that's why it's using it. To override it, you need to leave that option off and manually enter a different number.

Comment: Yes right. Now it's working.